# Stop browser from reading media queries

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, responsive-design

I'm building a responsive site, and as per usual IE7 is very difficult to accomodate. I was wondering if it is possible to switch off ALL media queries just for IE7, and still keep all the styling/layout as it is when in desktop mode?

Comment: You could try moving the media queries to a different stylesheet and use a conditional comment to load them. For more on conditional commenting, see [this site](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Comment: What are the media queries you're using?

Comment: What's the problem? IE7 doesn't support media queries, so it won't parse your media query CSS anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't need to switch of Media queries for IE7 because they are not supported in first place I believe.

The `@media` CSS code will get ignored.

I assume you are not using a polyfill for it though.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can make to different CSS files one for IE7 and another one for the other browsers. To select the stylesheet that fits to the user's browser use conditional comments in the "head" tag of your html file.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normal.css">
<![endif]>
```